# How to use window.postMessage to dynamic embedded iframes?

Tags: javascript, iframe, postmessage

I am having multiple dynamic frames on my page. All the iframes are under the same domain.
For example

```
<iframe src="data.php?id=1"> </iframe>
<iframe src="data.php?id=2"> </iframe>
<iframe src="data.php?id=3"> </iframe>
```

As you can see the iframes are linked to same page but with different id's.

So i am using a for loop to send the data to the iframe.(Code is below)

```
var iframes = document.getElementsByClassName('iframe');
for(var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++)
{
    iframes[i].contentWindow.postMessage("getName","http://localhost/data.php");
}
```

I am not sure what to put in the origin parameter of the `postMessage` function (i.e the second parameter).

On the iframe i have this code to process the message.

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
function receiveMessage(event)
{
    //event.source.postMessage("hi", event.origin);
    console.log('Message received');
}
```

But i didn't see anything in the console.

What's possibly is wrong??

> Update

I found that instead of using `postMessage` I can also access the content in javascript functions.
Now the problem is- I haven't figured a way how to accomplish this.

I want to access the `textnode` of the `title`element of the iframe by javascript.

Comment: When you say they're under the same domain, do you just mean with each other, or with the parent page as well?  If they're on the same domain as the parent page, you can bypass `postMessage` entirely and just call functions directly in the page

Comment: They are under the same domain and i am trying various options to access the `title` of the `iframe` using pure javascript but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get the titles of your iFrames.

```
var iframes = document.getElementsByClassName('iframe');
for(var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++){
    iframes[i].contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML;
}
```